# Differences between fork and exec

Tags: c, unix, fork, exec

What are the differences between `fork` and `exec`?

Comment: A good, detailed summary of fork, exec, and other process control functions is at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html

Comment: @Justin, because we want SO to become *the* place to go for programming questions.

Comment: so `fork` is basically cloning :O

Comment: this tutorial is also very helpful! https://devconnected.com/understanding-processes-on-linux/

Answer (score 428, accepted):

The use of `fork` and `exec` exemplifies the spirit of UNIX in that it provides a very simple way to start new processes.

The `fork` call basically makes a duplicate of the current process, identical in *almost* every way. Not everything is copied over (for example, resource limits in some implementations) but the idea is to create as close a copy as possible.

The new process (child) gets a different process ID (PID) and has the PID of the old process (parent) as its parent PID (PPID). Because the two processes are now running exactly the same code, they can tell which is which by the return code of `fork` - the child gets 0, the parent gets the PID of the child. This is all, of course, assuming the `fork` call works - if not, no child is created and the parent gets an error code.

The `exec` call is a way to basically replace the entire current process with a new program. It loads the program into the current process space and runs it from the entry point.

So, `fork` and `exec` are often used in sequence to get a new program running as a child of a current process. Shells typically do this whenever you try to run a program like `find` - the shell forks, then the child loads the `find` program into memory, setting up all command line arguments, standard I/O and so forth.

But they're not required to be used together. It's perfectly acceptable for a program to `fork` itself without `exec`ing if, for example, the program contains both parent and child code (you need to be careful what you do, each implementation may have restrictions). This was used quite a lot (and still is) for daemons which simply listen on a TCP port and `fork` a copy of themselves to process a specific request while the parent goes back to listening.

Similarly, programs that know they're finished and just want to run another program don't need to `fork`, `exec` and then `wait` for the child. They can just load the child directly into their process space.

Some UNIX implementations have an optimized `fork` which uses what they call copy-on-write. This is a trick to delay the copying of the process space in `fork` until the program attempts to change something in that space. This is useful for those programs using only `fork` and not `exec` in that they don't have to copy an entire process space.

If the `exec` *is* called following `fork` (and this is what happens mostly), that causes a write to the process space and it is then copied for the child process.

Note that there is a whole family of `exec` calls (`execl`, `execle`, `execve` and so on) but `exec` in context here means any of them.

The following diagram illustrates the typical `fork/exec` operation where the `bash` shell is used to list a directory with the `ls` command:

```
+--------+
| pid=7  |
| ppid=4 |
| bash   |
+--------+
    |
    | calls fork
    V
+--------+             +--------+
| pid=7  |    forks    | pid=22 |
| ppid=4 | ----------> | ppid=7 |
| bash   |             | bash   |
+--------+             +--------+
    |                      |
    | waits for pid 22     | calls exec to run ls
    |                      V
    |                  +--------+
    |                  | pid=22 |
    |                  | ppid=7 |
    |                  | ls     |
    V                  +--------+
+--------+                 |
| pid=7  |                 | exits
| ppid=4 | <---------------+
| bash   |
+--------+
    |
    | continues
    V
```

---

As an aside, there's [an interesting answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/process-model-in-early-unix/24424#24424) over on the [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange site](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) that details some history of `fork` and `exec`.

Answer (score 61):

`fork()` splits the current process into two processes. Or in other words, your nice linear easy to think of program suddenly becomes two separate programs running one piece of code:

```
 int pid = fork();

 if (pid == 0)
 {
     printf("I'm the child");
 }
 else
 {
     printf("I'm the parent, my child is %i", pid);
     // here we can kill the child, but that's not very parently of us
 }
```

This can kind of blow your mind. Now you have one piece of code with pretty much identical state being executed by two processes. The child process inherits all the code and memory of the process that just created it, including starting from where the `fork()` call just left off. The only difference is the `fork()` return code to tell you if you are the parent or the child. If you are the parent, the return value is the id of the child.

`exec` is a bit easier to grasp, you just tell `exec` to execute a process using the target executable and you don't have two processes running the same code or inheriting the same state. Like @Steve Hawkins says, `exec` can be used after you `fork`to execute in the current process the target executable.

Comment: there's also the condition when `pid < 0` and the `fork()` call failed

Comment: That doesn't blow my mind at all :-) One piece of code being executed by two processes happens every time a shared library or DLL is being used.

Answer (score 38):

I think some concepts from ["Advanced Unix Programming" by Marc Rochkind](http://basepath.com/aup/) were helpful in understanding the different roles of `fork()`/`exec()`, especially for someone used to the Windows `CreateProcess()` model:

> A *program* is a collection of instructions and data that is kept in a regular file on disk. (from 1.1.2 Programs, Processes, and Threads)

.

> In order to run a program, the kernel is first asked to create a new *process*, which is an environment in which a program executes. (also from 1.1.2 Programs, Processes, and Threads)

.

> It’s impossible to understand the exec or fork system calls without fully understanding the distinction between a process and a program. If these terms are new to you, you may want to go back and review Section 1.1.2. If you’re ready to proceed now, we’ll summarize the distinction in one sentence: A process is an execution environment that consists of instruction, user-data, and system-data segments, as well as lots of other resources acquired at runtime, whereas a program is a file containing instructions and data that are used to initialize the instruction and user-data segments of a process. (from 5.3 `exec` System Calls)

Once you understand the distinction between a program and a process, the behavior of `fork()` and `exec()` function can be summarized as:

- `fork()` creates a duplicate of the current process
- `exec()` replaces the program in the current process with another program

(this is essentially a simplified 'for dummies' version of [paxdiablo's much more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/exec-and-fork/1653415#1653415))

Answer (score 34):

Fork creates a copy of a calling process. 
generally follows the structure 
[image]

```
int cpid = fork( );

if (cpid = = 0) 
{

  //child code

  exit(0);

}

//parent code

wait(cpid);

// end
```

(for child process text(code),data,stack is same as calling process)
child process executes code in if block.

EXEC replaces the current process with new process's code,data,stack.
generally follows the structure 
[image]

```
int cpid = fork( );

if (cpid = = 0) 
{   
  //child code

  exec(foo);

  exit(0);    
}

//parent code

wait(cpid);

// end
```

(after exec call unix kernel clears the child process text,data,stack and fills with foo process related text/data)
thus child process is with different code (foo's code {not same as parent})

Comment: It' s a bit unrelated to the question but doesn't this code above cause a race condition if child process happen to finish it's code first? In that case, parent process would hang around forever waiting the child to terminate itself, right?

Comment: @stdout: it's a bit late answering your question but I don't think a race condition occurs. When a process exits before a parent waits on it, it enters a zombie state (it's dead but still hanging around somewhat). The bit that's hanging around is basically the exit code, so that the parent can eventually `wait` and receive that info. At that point, the zombie disappears fully. And, if the parent disappears first, the `init` process inherits the child and eventually reaps the exit process (when child exits).

Answer (score 7):

They are use together to create a new child process.  First, calling `fork` creates a copy of the current process (the child process).  Then, `exec` is called from within the child process to "replace" the copy of the parent process with the new process.

The process goes something like this:

```
child = fork();  //Fork returns a PID for the parent process, or 0 for the child, or -1 for Fail

if (child < 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to fork GUI process...Exiting" << std::endl;
    exit (-1);
} else if (child == 0) {       // This is the Child Process
    // Call one of the "exec" functions to create the child process
    execvp (argv[0], const_cast<char**>(argv));
} else {                       // This is the Parent Process
    //Continue executing parent process
}
```

Comment: In 7th line it is mentioned that exec() function creates the child process.. Is it really so because fork() has already created the child process and exec() call just replaces the program of the new process just created

Answer (score 7):

The main difference between `fork()` and `exec()` is that,

The `fork()` system call creates a clone of the currently running program. The original program continues execution with the next line of code after the fork() function call. The clone also starts execution at the next line of code. 
Look at the following code that i got from http://timmurphy.org/2014/04/26/using-fork-in-cc-a-minimum-working-example/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("--beginning of program\n");
    int counter = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child process
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            printf("child process: counter=%d\n", ++counter);
        }
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        // parent process
        int j = 0;
        for (; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            printf("parent process: counter=%d\n", ++counter);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // fork failed
        printf("fork() failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("--end of program--\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This program declares a counter variable, set to zero, before `fork()`ing. After the fork call, we have two processes running in parallel, both incrementing their own version of counter. Each process will run to completion and exit. Because the processes run in parallel, we have no way of knowing which will finish first. Running this program will print something similar to what is shown below, though results may vary from one run to the next.

```
--beginning of program
parent process: counter=1
parent process: counter=2
parent process: counter=3
child process: counter=1
parent process: counter=4
child process: counter=2
parent process: counter=5
child process: counter=3
--end of program--
child process: counter=4
child process: counter=5
--end of program--
```

The `exec()` family of system calls replaces the currently executing code of a process with another piece of code. The process retains its PID but it becomes a new program. For example, consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
main() {
 char program[80],*args[3];
 int i; 
printf("Ready to exec()...\n"); 
strcpy(program,"date"); 
args[0]="date"; 
args[1]="-u"; 
args[2]=NULL; 
i=execvp(program,args); 
printf("i=%d ... did it work?\n",i); 
}
```

This program calls the `execvp()` function to replace its code with the date program. If the code is stored in a file named exec1.c, then executing it produces the following output:

```
Ready to exec()... 
Tue Jul 15 20:17:53 UTC 2008
```

The program outputs the line ―Ready to exec() . . . ‖ and after calling the execvp() function, replaces its code with the date program. Note that the line ― . . . did it work‖ is not displayed, because at that point the code has been replaced. Instead, we see the output of executing ―date -u.‖

Answer (score 4):

fork() creates a copy of the current process, with execution in the new child starting from just after the fork() call.  After the fork(), they're identical, except for the return value of the fork() function.  (RTFM for more details.)  The two processes can then diverge still further, with one unable to interfere with the other, except possibly through any shared file handles.

exec() replaces the current process with a new one.  It has nothing to do with fork(), except that an exec() often follows fork() when what's wanted is to launch a different child process, rather than replace the current one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]`fork()`:

It creates a copy of running process. The running process is called **parent process** & newly created process is called **child process**. The  way to differentiate the two is by looking at the returned value:

1. `fork()` returns the process identifier (pid) of the child process in the parent
2. `fork()` returns 0 in the child.

`exec()`:

It initiates a new process within a process. It  loads a new program into the current process, replacing the existing one.

`fork()` + `exec()`:

When launching a new program is to firstly `fork()`, creating a new process, and then `exec()` (i.e. load into memory and execute) the program binary it is supposed to run.

```
int main( void ) 
{
    int pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0 ) 
    {
        execvp( "find", argv );
    }

    //Put the parent to sleep for 2 sec,let the child finished executing 
    wait( 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prime example to understand the `fork()` and `exec()` concept is the ***shell***,the command interpreter program that users typically executes after logging into the system.The shell interprets the first word of **command line** as a *command* name

For many commands,the *shell* ***forks*** and the child process ***execs*** the command associated with the name treating the remaining words on the command line as parameters to the command.

The *shell* allows three types of commands. First, a command can be an
**executable file** that contains object code produced by compilation of *source code* (a C program for example). Second, a command can be an executable file that
contains a sequence of shell command lines. Finally, a command can be an internal shell command.(instead of an executable file ex->**cd**,**ls** etc.)