# Both fork() and the exec() system calls

Tags: exec, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [exec and fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/exec-and-fork)

Both fork() and the exec() system calls eventually cause the execution of a
program (i.e. of a sequence of machine instructions) by the CPU. Explain how
their behavior differs with respect to:
(a) Process control;
(b) Call and return; and
(c) Which program is being executed?

Comment: This is the exact wording to a homework problem my friend asked me for help on.

Answer (score -4):

fork() and exec() are deprecated. You should use spoon().

Comment: -1 not a real answer. Feel free to downvote the question, or even flag it, if you think the question is inappropriate. But providing worthless answers degrades the quality of this site, and helps nobody.