# Forks & Shared Memory

Tags: c, pointers, process, operating-system, fork

If a process and its fork have different copies of the data, then why is their pointer the same?

In the example below, if count was shared between the parent and child processes, we would see `count: 2`. However, count is not shared. But then, why does `&count` return the same value in both the parent and child process?

Output:

```
count: 1 0x7fff5a617510
count: 1 0x7fff5a617510
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int count = 0;

    pid = fork();

    count++;
    printf("count: %d %p \n", count, &count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's virtual addressing. The address your process sees doesn't correspond directly to physical addresses.

Comment: Is there a way to see the physical address?

Comment: Hmm.  The output for me is:  `error: 'new_count' undeclared (first use in this function)`.  :)

Comment: This question has already been answered here!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253659/why-the-address-of-variable-of-child-process-and-parent-process-is-same

Comment: @Tatterdemalion Thanks, I could not find that. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @luqmaan That shouldn't be necessary, a duplicate question may make it easier for the next person to find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, this is because of virtual addressing. AFAIK there is no way to see the physical address, as this is handled by the kernel and the MMU.

Also, note than even if count was shared between the two process (using shared memory; see `man shmget` for example), there would be a race condition.