# How to start another program without having to wait on it in C++?

Tags: c++

How can I make a C++ program start another program/process (C++ specifically) and not wait for it to end? (so `system()` won't work here because it starts the other program/process as child, right?)

I was thinking about starting the second program/process on another thread or something but I'm not sure if that would work.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Running linux, sorry for missin that precision... (ubuntu 11.10 to be precise)

Comment: The usual solution is to fork()/exec()

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/exec-and-fork

Comment: What you're looking for is [Fork and Exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/exec-and-fork/1653349#1653349)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a fork with `fork()` (or `clone()` if you wanted threads rather than jobs), and then run the program using `execve()` or `system()` in one process, and continue running the original program in the other.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `nohup` with system(). So your called c++ program will work in the background but your other c++ program will get the exit signal from nohup and finish the system call. E.g.:

```
 system("nohup gedit &")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this on Unix/Linux, you could use `fork` and a derivative of `exec`, where `fork` will basically create a new process by duplicating the current one. You can then also use `wait` or `waitpid` to wait for the child and retrieve it's exit status.

EDIT: damn it people always post faster than me. xD

Answer (score 0):

If it's for MS Windows, [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the way to do it. Quote: `Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization.`