# Fork()-ing a new process

Tags: linux, process, exec, creation

Fork()-ing a process will end up calling do_fork() inside kernel, making an exact copy of itself. When I read through books, it says that child of fork will call exec to create the new process.

example:

ls command on a shell, will create this way.

```
   sh(Parent)
       |
   sh(Child)
       |
   ls(New Process)
```

But, I am not able to understand how & where the exec*() is called?
Because, All I can see is the shell(child) is what created in fork.
But, when and where will the new process be created/executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You* have to `exec()` if you actually want a new program running in one of the processes (usually the child but not absolutely necessary). In your specific case where the shell executes `ls`, the shell first forks, then the child process execs. But it's important to realise that this is two *distinct* operations.

All `fork()` does is give you two (nearly) identical processes and you can then use the return code from `fork()` to decide if you're the parent (you get the positive PID of the child, or -1 if the `fork()` failed) or child (you get 0).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/exec-and-fork/1653415#1653415) for a description on how `fork()` and `exec()` work together (under *your* control) and how they can be used without each other.

Similar to `do_fork()`, the `exec` stuff all boils down to calls to `do_execve`, located in [`exec.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me where the exec() is wrapped around in kernel?

Comment: The `exec` is a separate system call.  The `fork()` returns twice (when it is successful), once in the child process, and once in the parent.  What happens next is up to the code in the process.

Comment: @Saran-san, I've updated the answer with the kernel `exec` details.

Comment: The syscall is actually [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Other [exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions are calling `execve`. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ which has a nice and complete explanations about your question.