# Handling signals in C after execl

Tags: c, signals

I have problem with handling signals. I run program in terminal, I am pressed CTRL + C, but don't see "I am pressed CTRL-C" wasn't printed. But I am trying delete row `execl("/usr/bin/gedit", "gedit", "test.c", NULL)`, "I am pressed CTRL-C" was printed.

Can I help you, how to print "I am pressed CTRL-C" and explain why it is. I am appreciated of your help. Thank you very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int loop_forever = 1;

void on_sigint()
{
    printf("\nI am pressed CTRL-C\n");
    loop_forever = 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("My homework\n");

    execl("/usr/bin/gedit", "gedit", "test.c", NULL);
    signal(SIGINT, on_sigint);
    while (loop_forever)
    {
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execl` executes another program *in place of* yours.

Basically, it transforms your process into a `gedit` process. Your code will no longer execute, and gedit will run in its place.

To run another program *separate from* yours, you can use

```
if(!fork()) {
  execl("/usr/bin/gedit", "gedit", "test.c", NULL);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/differences-between-exec-and-fork) for a detailed description of how `fork` and `exec` works in the Unix process model.

Comment: I am understanding that you said. Thank you very much.