# Perl directory change from Windows cmd.exe

Tags: perl, cmd, chdir

According to the manual, [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html), *Changes the working directory to `EXPR`, if possible.*

This script, when executed from cmd.exe:

```
my $path = 'C:\\some\\path\\';
print "$path\n";
chdir("$path") or die "fail $!";
```

results in this output:

```
C:\some\path\
```

but when I am returned to the command prompt - I'm still at the original directory. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of chdir?

Comment: @Sinan: was it really necessary to edit out my "Thanks!" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a shell runs a program, it essentially forks then execs the program -- in this case, your perl script.  The directory within that forked process has been changed, and then that process dies.  You're then returned to the original shell process.

Comment: yup - that would make sense. could I spawn another cmd.exe instance starting it at the appropriate directory?

Comment: Erm, no such thing as `fork` on Windows. It's just that the directory the Perl script is using is not the one that the shell uses.

Comment: Sure there's fork() on Windows.  Cygin emulates it quite completely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork  But, you'll note I used the words "essentially forks".  It probably is using CreateProcess ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx ) on the backend at some point.

Comment: @dls: You can always just execut cmd from your perl script with system('cmd')  That'll start up a command shell in the desired directory.  That call to system will return when somebody types 'exit' to exit the cmd shell.

Comment: this accomplishes what I'm after:

system("cmd /K cd /d $final_dest");

where $final_dest is the desired path..

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

See the FAQ [I {changed directory, modified my environment} in a perl script. How come the change disappeared when I exited the script? How do I get my changes to be visible?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#I-%7bchanged-directory,-modified-my-environment%7d-in-a-perl-script.--How-come-the-change-disappeared-when-I-exited-the-script%3f--How-do-I-get-my-changes-to-be-visible%3f)

> In the strictest sense, it can't be done—the script executes as a different process from the shell it was started from. Changes to a process are not reflected in its parent—only in any children created after the change.

The same answer applies to Windows as well.

You can modify the starting directory of subsequent `cmd.exe` invocations, or of child processes by messing with shortcuts and/or the registry.

Answer (score 1):

I have changing directories and command environments by using the perl `-x` switch to execute Perl code in embedded in a file.

```
@rem = '--*-Perl-*--'
@echo off
set TMPBAT=%TMP%\%0_temp.bat
perl -x -S %0 %*
if %errorlevel% == 2000 goto cleanup
goto endofperl
#!perl
#line 9

use strict;
use warnings; 
use BatchTool;


__END__
:endofperl
if exist %TMPBAT% call %TMPBAT%
:cleanup
set TMPBAT=
```

`BatchTool` is a module that writes DOS commands to `$ENV{TMPBAT}` if 1) it doesn't exist or 2) is older than the source script.