# Library that has reference to fork() in C

Tags: c, fork

What is the library that defines fork(). I am learning to use fork(). I found out that the Standard I/O Library : `stdio.h`  is enough for fork() to work but that does not apply in my case.

I am using `gcc` in `Code::Blocks` on `Windows 8 Pro`

My Code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{

    pid_t process;
    process = fork();

    if(process< 0)
    {
        printf("fork failed");
    }
    if(process > 0)
    {
        printf("\nParent Process Executed");
    }

    if(process == 0)
    {
        printf("\nChild Process Executed");
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

The Exact Error I get is:

> useoffork.o:useoffork.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `fork'

Comment: this may help you man fork...http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to fork() in Code::Blocks editor in Windows OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819673/undefined-reference-to-fork-in-codeblocks-editor-in-windows-os)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard library (glibc) implements `fork()` which calls a UNIX/Linux-specific system call eventually to create a process, on Windows, you should use the winapi [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) see this example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note: Cygwin `fork()` is just a wrapper around `CreateProcess()` see [How is fork() implemented?](http://cygwin.com/cygwin/faq/faq.api.html#faq.api.fork)

Comment: what should i include for that? @mux ?

Comment: @cipher the link has an example

Comment: i needed basic thing in `C` And your link is regarding `C++` . Anywaysm Thanks for the help.

Comment: @cipher no it's not C++ specific, see this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually, `fork()` is a Unix thing, it's specified by POSIX (and SVr4 and BSD, see [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). It's not part of the C standard.

Comment: @unwind I didn't say it's standard C I said the C standard library usually implements it :)

Comment: @cipher You should accept this answer instead of mine. It's more informative.

Comment: If that's what you yourself say. I will go with that

Answer (score 3):

> I am using gcc in Code::Blocks on Windows 8 Pro

You don't have `fork` on windows. You can use cygwin or something like that though.

Comment: alternate solution for windows without using cygwin?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL Don't use `fork`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

The  C library  defines `fork()`.

It is the UNIX/Linux-specific system calls to create a process, on linux etc.