# What is the error in the program?

Tags: c, system, fork

I wrote this basics forking program in C language. But the compiler issues me error. The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void childProcess(){
    printf("From child process with process id %d\n", getpid());
}


void parentProcess(){
    printf("Parent Process with id %d\n", getpid());
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        childProcess();
    } else if (pid > 0){
        printf("Parent spawned process %d\n", pid);
    } else{
        printf("Forking isn't supported!\n");
    }

}

int main(){
    parentProcess();

}
```

The error is

```
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccORJc6N.o forking.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `fork'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Windows, looks like you can't do that on Windows. Here are some related posts:

- [Undefined reference to fork() in Code::Blocks editor in Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819673/undefined-reference-to-fork-in-codeblocks-editor-in-windows-os)
- [Why does my compiler not accept fork(), despite my inclusion of <unistd.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612315/why-does-my-compiler-not-accept-fork-despite-my-inclusion-of-unistd-h)
- [Library that has reference to fork() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643278/library-that-has-reference-to-fork-in-c) <- The answer to this one may be helpful to you

These were the first three links when googling your error: undefined reference to `fork'

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a library:

Add this to the top of your code

```
#include  <sys/types.h>
```

Comment: This is a linker error.  Adding a header won't fix the issue.

Comment: He didn't specify windows and his error is associated with pid_t reference. If it is on windows then yup you're correct

Comment: Actually, this IS the error in the program. The other error, the current most-voted answer, is actually an error in the users choice of OS. Keep in mind that the question is about *the error in the program*, and missing an include might actually cause such linker errors... Assuming the correct OS, @JimLewis, this WOULD actually fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

To unify the best answers I see so far (which aren't necessarily the most popular):

- [According to the `fork` manual, you're missing the `<unistd.h>` header include](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) ([and `<sys/types>`, depending on the POSIX standard you use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fork.html)). Note that this is an error in the program when a POSIX-compliant OS is targeted, which brings me to the next point:
- Those will only work on POSIX-compliant OSes that support `fork`, of course... and Windows is not one of them. Note that this isn't an error in *the program*; it's an error in *the selection of the OS*.

I found another error in the program. `%d` tells `printf` to print an argument of type `int`, but the actual type you've provided is `pid_t`. According to [the `printf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) (which I highly recommend reading and fully understanding multiple times for the purpose of writing better code; you'll learn *a lot*), "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined." You need an explicit conversion. For example:

```
printf("From child process with process id %d\n", (int) getpid());
printf("Parent Process with id %d\n", (int) getpid());
printf("Parent spawned process %d\n", (int) pid);
```

The conversion to `int` is itself an error; according to [the `<sys/types.h>` header manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), a POSIX-compliant implementation "shall support one or more programming environments in which the widths of `blksize_t`, `pid_t`, `size_t`, `ssize_t`, `suseconds_t`, and `useconds_t` are no greater than the width of type `long`." In such an environment, a conversion to `long` and using the corresponding `%ld` (that's an *ell*, by the way) directive would be more appropriate:

```
printf("From child process with process id %ld\n", (long) getpid());
printf("Parent Process with id %ld\n", (long) getpid());
printf("Parent spawned process %ld\n", (long) pid);
```