# How can I start a sub-process in Windows?

Tags: windows, fork

In POSIX, there is the `fork()` function to create a sub-process. How can I achieve `fork()`'s functionality in Windows?

Comment: What do want to know? How to create a thread programming on Windows?

Comment: oh, no , I hava a trouble when i study linux... On Windows, we can use the function CreateThread(...) to creat a thread. But on Linux ,There is a function fork() to create a child process, I want to know  wehter  there is function similar to fork() on Window...

Comment: As far as i know yu can use _spawn(), _beginthread() and _endthread().

Comment: Ah, This is a other way to create a thread, But can we create a process?

Comment: Ether i'm a bit thick or your manner of posing  question is quite unique ... anyway there is CreateProcess(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Related discussion: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/360290-fork-on-windows/

Comment: yes, I understand what you mean. Thank you ...

Comment: Perhaps _spawn* in process.h may be sufficient: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46236161/2630028

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of `fork()` on Windows.

[`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the native function that can be used to create a new process (but, again, the semantics are rather different to `fork()`'s).

To put this another way, on Unix it is possible for a process to cheaply create a clone of itself. There is no inexpensive way to do this on Windows.

If you don't care about the cloning aspect of `fork()`, then `CreateProcess()` should do just fine.

Comment: But, what is different between CreateProcess() and fork() ?

Comment: @Tu_JianWu: the new process created by fork() inherits the parent's state, including the value of variables and the current instruction pointer.  The new process created by CreateProcess() doesn't, it is started from scratch.  Also fork() can only create a new copy of the executable that is already running, CreateProcess() can launch any exectuable.