# C++ - Making a program open itself

Tags: c++

I have a program that opens a WAV file and then plots the waveform. If the WAV file has 2 channels, two graphs are shown, one for each channel. It's working fine but I want to add things in the File Menu that I created. So far, I have three buttons: `New`, `Open File`, and `Close`. So far, the `Open File` and the `Close` buttons are working fine.

I want to make the program to be able to let the user view several waveforms of several WAV Files at the same time. One option would be to create more graphs, the process would be quite tedious. Another option would be to open another window and this is what I want to do.

However, this is my problem. I made a quick search on how to open an existing program in C++, and so far, the solutions that I encounter involve opening an exe file and the project folder does not contain an exe file.

I also tried to take a quick look on the functions and I can't find the function that seems to open the window and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You don't need to create a new program just to show a new window, whatever widget library you are using should be capable of displaying multiple windows.

Comment: Yes, I prefer "more windows" (or more Tabs within the window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). Alternatively you could use [threads](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

Comment: I know this would sound stupid but I'm using wxDev-C++ as my platform. fork(); does not seem to work properly.

Comment: @Razgriz In what way (is this windows).

Comment: Yes, it is windows. I tried including the unistd.h header file via `#include <unistd.h>`. I'll try to copy paste everything and include it via `#include "unistd.h"`

Comment: I tried `pid_t fork(void);` and `fork()`, the former does not work and the latter gives the following error: `[Linker Error] undefined reference to `fork()'`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147941/how-can-i-start-a-sub-process-in-windows

Comment: This does answer the question of how to spawn another process, but makes no mention of the fact that spawning another process is absolutely unnecessary for solving the problem the OP has.

Comment: @cubic - I do not know the architecture of the s/W. Perhaps it is easier to have a separate process or thread. It does not specify the platform. I am sure that the perform has adequate fibre as to looking up fork or its moral equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetModuleFileName` API to get the path+ name of your executable. Then Use `ShellExecute` to run this APP.

Comment: How do you know he is on windows?

Comment: The author specifically tells about "exe"file so it must be windows