# Configure Multiprocessing in python to use forkserver

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

How can I configure multiprocessing **in Windows** to use the 'forkserver' method?
whenever I start up IPython console and type:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
```

the error:

```
ValueError: cannot find context for 'forkserver'
```

occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`forkserver` is only available in Python 3.4+ and only on some Unix platforms (not on Windows).

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods):

> `forkserver`
>
> > **Available on Unix platforms which support passing file descriptors over Unix pipes.**
>
> Changed in version 3.4: [...] `forkserver` added for **some unix
>   platforms**.

The reason `forkserver` is not available on Windows is that it relies on [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)), and there is no `fork()` on Windows. For more information, see [How can I start a sub-process in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147941/how-can-i-start-a-sub-process-in-windows)