# how to call 2 or more shellexecute functions in a program

Tags: c++, winapi, system, shellexecute, execv

I am a beginner in winapi c++ on windows platform, i need to execute 3 exe files,i.e the installation programs, in one single program. i used shellexecute, exec v, system calls but all are exiting the program after the first program installation, please help me to solve this...

part of the code I used

```
ShellExecute( hwndDlg, "open", "calc.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL );

status = execv(".\\InstallationFiles\\dotnetfx 35 SP1 Full.exe",child_args);
```

Thanking you in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is it that you want to execute the three processes one after the other. So, you execute one, wait for it finish, then execute the next, and so on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, i have 3 exe files(requisites for another app), here I check the availability of these requisites, and if one is not available in the user system, the program should run the particular exe file, after its successful installation, it should check for further requisites. pls help

Comment: You want to call `CreateProcess` to start each task. Then call `WaitForSingleObject` passing the process handled returned by `CreateProcess`. That will then block until the task is complete. Then move on to the next task.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry for late reply, Thanks lot, but it works partially only, the second process is not waiting till the app 1 is installed completely, what to do.

Comment: No, WaitForSingleObject is known to work. You cannot expect us to explain what's up with your code when we cannot see it. Also do be aware that your question is terribly vague. You'll get much better help if you make more effort and ask better questions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes thanks so much, it is working now, how can i make this installer silent, I hope you got my problem please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use WinAPI (one of your tags) you should use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. [Here](http://www.goffconcepts.com/techarticles/development/cpp/createprocess.html) are some examples.

`exec*` family according to [manual](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execv.htm):

> The exec family of functions **replaces the current process** image with a
>   new process image. The functions described in this manual page are
>   front-ends for the function execve(2). (See the manual page for execve
>   for detailed information about the replacement of the current
>   process.)

So if you want to stick to `exec` family functions you need to use some sort of [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) which brings [some problems under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork), but here's an ["linux-like" example](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html).

Comment: the commands you mentioned are for linux or unix based systems , its different for windows

Comment: @Paul Windows solution is `CreateProcess`, everything else is just a wrapper leading to that api call

Comment: @thanks Vyktor, but after the execution of one exe file does the rest of the codes run using create process.