# Is there any open-source cross-platform library for working with processes in C?

Tags: c, process, open-source

Not C++ like [boost::process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process0.5/boost_process/tutorial.html) or [Qt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html) but plain C. Is there any open-source cross-platform C library for working with processes?

Comment: What is a "process library"?

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `fork()` and `exec()` good enough from the standard library?

Comment: @H2CO3: `fork()` on windows?)

Comment: You might also need wait() and friends and maybe pause() and setgid() and friends

Comment: @myWallJSON I practically don't care Microsoft writes nonstandard [software] crap :P

Comment: and if possible `close/kill`

Comment: @H2CO3: thats why I seek for a crossplatform one=) for WINDOWS, LINUX AND MAC=))

Comment: Windows is not a platform. It is a *software ecosystem* (with only one top-predator: Steve Ballmer)

Comment: @wildplasser neither one. Windows is an antipattern.

Comment: I guess we could form the *gang of two* here ... Famous Henry Spencer quote: *anyone who ignores unix is doomed to reinvent it. Poorly*

Comment: You could use preprocessor macros to call the right function for every system.

Answer (score 1):

[glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) (think Gnome) is the peer of Qt (think Kde) but being written in C.  There is a section titled [Spawning Processes](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve and what you mean by "cross platform", you could write everything to target POSIX and just use Cygwin for your Windows port.  I think that covers Linux, Unix, OSX (aka BSD), and Windows XP - Win 7, and any RTOS with a POSIX layer (e.g. QNX).  Not sure if Cygwin works on Win 8.

See also:
[What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork)