# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vfork referenced in function _main

Tags: c

My Goal is to get outputs from Critical Section `C` Program (Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7). I get the following errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vfork referenced in function _main
error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

My Code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int turn;
int flag[2];
int main(void)
{
    int pid, parent = 1;
    printf("before vfork\n");
    if ((pid = vfork())<0)
    {
        perror("vfork error\n");
        return 1;

    }
    while (1)
    {
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            while (parent == 1)
            {
                sleep(2);
            }
            parent = 0;
            flag[0] = 1;
            turn = 1;
            while (flag[1] && turn == 1);
            printf("This is critical section:parent process\n");
            flag[0] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = 2;
            printf("This is parent");
            flag[1] = 1;
            turn = 0;
            while (flag[0] && turn == 0);
            printf("This is critical section:child process %d \n", pid);
            flag[1] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not implement the `vfork()` system call; it is generally only available on UNIX systems. You will need to use threads to implement equivalent functionality.

Information on using threads in Windows is available in the Windows Dev Center under "[Processes and Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841.aspx)".

---

Please note that, as written, **your program invokes undefined behavior**. The POSIX.1 specification explains that:

> …behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()`
>   either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to
>   store  the  return  value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in
>   which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function  before  successfully
>   calling `_exit(2)` or one of the `exec(3)` family of functions.

To make a long story short, you can only use `vfork()` to lead up to an `exec()`. It cannot safely be used for anything else at all.

Comment: I think maybe the OP intended to use [Cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/985281/1174378)...

Comment: Dear duskwuff, thanks for information. As keeping the development tools and the OS is not compulsory, I can implement the same concept using any OS. For Unix, can Linux also support this program? If yes, then Ubunto 10?

Comment: Yes, Linux is one such system. However, mind the notes I'm adding to my post.