# Two way parent child communication in windows with c++

Tags: c++, windows, parent-child, child-process

**Scroll down to see new update**

**Update::
In other word: I want to launch another program in the manner of a shell on Windows.**

Need a two way communication between parent and child process using c++ on Windows. The parent is my program and the child is a random console application (like mysql terminal).

It's been a couple days searching but couldn't find any working solution for Windows. Also MS documentations is not helping.

Here i got a sample code from a question asked three years ago. How can i translate the code to Microsoft specific api and use it on Windows?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define Read            0
#define Write           1
#define ParentRead      read_pipe[1]
#define ParentWrite     write_pipe[0]
#define ChildRead       write_pipe[1]
#define ChildWrite      read_pipe[0]

int main()
{
int data_processed;

/** Pipe for reading for subprocess */
int read_pipe[2];
/** Pipe for writing to subprocess */
int write_pipe[2];

char buffer[100];
memset(buffer, '\0', 100);

if (pipe(read_pipe) == 0 && pipe(write_pipe) == 0)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == (pid_t)-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid == (pid_t)0) //Child process
    {
        close(Read);
        close(Write);
        close(ParentRead);
        close(ParentWrite);
        dup(ChildRead);
        dup(ChildWrite);
        execlp("cat", (char*)NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else { //Parent process
        close(ChildRead);
        close(ChildWrite);

        write(ParentWrite, "abc", 3);
        int r = read(ParentRead, buffer, 99);
        printf("%d %d", r, errno);
        puts(buffer);
    }
}

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**New Update:**

So based on [this sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) I wrote a modified version of the sample code and seems to be OK except that the redirected output is not what it's supposed to be. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

HANDLE hSTD_IN_READ = NULL;
HANDLE hSTD_IN_WRITE = NULL;
HANDLE hSTD_OUT_READ = NULL;
HANDLE hSTD_OUT_WRITE = NULL;

void WriteToPipe(std::string);
void ReadFromPipe();


int main()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    std::cout << "\nStart of parent execution: ";

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create pip for child process stdout
    if (!CreatePipe(&hSTD_OUT_READ, &hSTD_OUT_WRITE, &sa, 0)) {
        std::cout << "Error: CreatePipe STDOUT.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for stdout is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hSTD_OUT_READ, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        std::cout << "Error: STD_OUT_READ CreatePipe.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    // Create pipe for child process's stdin
    if (!CreatePipe(&hSTD_IN_READ, &hSTD_IN_WRITE, &sa, 0)) {
        std::cout << "Error: CreatePipe STDIN.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hSTD_IN_WRITE, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        std::cout << "Error: STD_IN_WRITE CreatePipe.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    // Create Child Process

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = hSTD_OUT_WRITE;
    si.hStdInput = hSTD_IN_READ;
    si.hStdOutput = hSTD_OUT_WRITE;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    bSuccess = CreateProcess(TEXT("c:\\sqlite3.exe"), NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    if (!bSuccess) {
        std::cout << "Error in CreateProcess.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    // Now execute your command then read the child process's output.
    WriteToPipe(".databases");
    ReadFromPipe();

    std::cout << "End of program.\n";
    return 0;
}

void WriteToPipe(std::string buffer)
{
    DWORD bWritten, BUFFSIZE = buffer.size();
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;


        bSuccess = WriteFile(hSTD_IN_WRITE, buffer.c_str(), BUFFSIZE, &bWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess)
            std::cout << "WritetoPipe::Couldn't Write to std_in_write.\n";

        // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading.
        if (!CloseHandle(hSTD_IN_WRITE))
            std::cout << "WriteToPipe::Couldn't close the handle after Writing to std_in_write.\n";
    }

void ReadFromPipe()
{
    DWORD bRead, bWritten;
    const DWORD BUFFSIZE = 4096;
    CHAR buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hPARENT_STD_OUT = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;) {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hSTD_OUT_READ, buffer, BUFFSIZE, &bRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || bRead == 0) {
            std::cout << "ReadFromPipe::Exiting after ReadFile.\n";
            break;
        }
        bSuccess = WriteFile(hPARENT_STD_OUT, buffer, BUFFSIZE, &bWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            std::cout << "ReadFromPipe::Exiting after WriteFile.\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Start of parent execution: seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main
ówVE_■   öΘ/ P╞ów    (┴M (┴M         êΘ/ (┴M     £Θ/ ╕å¥w  M áΘ/ ,╟₧w     Ω/ fr#u  M ╝îíw@r#u╕   (∞/     @∩/        ΣΘ/ @               @∩/ (∞/ ⁿΘ/ ép#u@∩/ (∞/ @∩/ <ε/ o#u(∞/ @∩/ 8∩/ 4o#u┘╥₧w        ╓   ┤Ω/ ┘jƒw  M A÷₧w  M A÷₧wÿìM     ■≤₧w╪½└(     M    8┘M     M A÷₧wÿìM  ²   ¿½└(ªfM   M ~fM   xçM δ/   M A÷₧wxêM     ■≤₧wx¼└(      M    ╚½└(  M            δ/ ù    wáw  Vδ/ ╓   |δ/ ┘jƒwⁿδ/ Vδ/   ½└(αφ/ ⁿδ/
kƒw
kƒw    ⁿδ/ ░δ/ (°     M ╚╜M ΦÉM    îM Ç   ÉìM └ 3 6 9 5 7 \   ╨φ/ |δ/ πlƒw╢êM ¿δ/ \   αφ/ ^      ¼φ/ πiƒw╨φ/ áδ/     `ε/ ≥iƒw    ┐M \ ^ ¿δ/ S -   M A÷₧wÿêM     ■≤₧wP¡└(p     M h   1 6 2 2 ╠ ╔8 0   - 3 6 9 5 7 ╠ ╔8 1 4 - öfM 0 1       &▄₧w  B·  A÷₧w       ÿêM c : ┘╥₧w@¡└(  M ÉêM     ╠ ╔  M ╠ ╔ê├M   äM Ç   ╨∞/ ╠ ╔φ/ Ä╘Γ á∞/
╬M    \φ/        φ/ \φ/ ╠ ╔=·  zφ/   M ÉêM ñÉM ≡∞/ Ç    ë½w┬ÇƒwL  |φ/    ÿêM      └&       ê╤M ╕∞/           /  ówVE_■   dφ/ P╞ów    ÿêM ÿêM ╕φ/ á∩/     ÿêM     `M S B _ E tφ/ ,╟₧w    ÿêM °∩/ @X#u  M     ÿêM     É±/ SX#áwÉ±/ ┐M                               Ç±/     P   P6*uá∩/ ÿêM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               WΓF┼CÑ■ ìεπ╙≡WΓF┼CÑ■ ìεπ╙≡                           _╩╝H±/ ñU#u          Ç±/     t⌠/ ▒U#u
        (                                                                                                             ┘╥₧w╨▒└(┘╥₧w╪▒└(  M ┐M     ╚▒└(  M ░╛M             ≈         NM    ╠ ╔                              α╛M   M ░╛M ±   ▒X#u   ░╛M Ç      Ç      (╟M     ╕╛M ╠  └ M    L       ëM ╕╛M    ÿêM              ╪ÅM    ╪ÅM    `M ówVE_■   ▄±/ P╞ów    ┐M   M         ╕╛M ┐M ╕╛M     α±/ ╕╛M Φ±/ ,╟₧w    ⁿ±/ ?ñ#u  M     ┐M ╚≈/     ╚≈/ g⌡Θv╩ê∞v╬∩Θv╪D╔@┬Q┌ P_$u    ╬ ╧ ╨ ╤ ╥ ╙ ╘ ╒ ╓ ╫ ╪ ┘ ┌ █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ α ß Γ π Σ σ                                                     αëM         â   É▀█ D       'M                                            ö   É   É   l@                       L      é£        "   ┐M ?      α²    √   @┤└(└           └ M                +   M     >  >          M        └ M                M ░  &  &  M H          ñ   ¿                 @   ≡²     α²             á&    `°/                        £  t  h╝M     +             █               [           h  @           M                                                        P°/ ┐M ╨⌡/  α² ╨&  °█     ¿                 ██                     ╕╛M
                       ¿       ■≤₧  └(    ñ              ╕╛M                  °█ c               └        M █  █'   └ M Ω    X╝M &         └     ■       ┘╥₧wá   £   £  t          └ M Ç   @   @  ñ     °█ $ & Φ╛M                                                           ╠⌠v   î÷/ á÷/ PΩ¥w╠⌠vî÷/       H⌠v   |⌠vH⌠v ⌠v▌Θ¥w░÷/         └≈/ ≤τ¥w┬Q┌ ÿ   Φ¥w    2   ⌠v  ⌠v   ì                °≈/ H⌠v                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ⌠╢└(∞≈/ ┤ïΘv½½½½╝îíw╪ïΘvÿ   ┬Q┌ φïΘv░┌ ÿ   ⁿD╔@°/ ╩┌ ÿ   ■┌
   ┌S╙╫∞°/ Φå█     ┤°/ 8┌ .databas
```

Comment: One way is to use named pipes, documentation and sample code is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx For the client you probably want to inject a listener via CreateRemoteThread.

Comment: Have a look at the [client and server samples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) for [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: See [What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork) and you may want to look at the documentation for the `spawn()` function [_spawn, _wspawn Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx)

Comment: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you all for responding. Right now I'm struggling with named pipes and studying MS docs which has confused me don't know how am i supposed to execute external console apps like cmd or mysql terminal.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Thanks but I've seen that before.

Comment: @fassl The [Multithreaded pipe server sample code on MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) confused me. Should i use CreateProcess() func with a modified version of the sample?

Comment: For using cmd u could call system("command"); i think. Also i dont know if i understood your question correctly... You want to communicate with another app, not redirect the output of another app to your app like other comments here suggest, right?

Comment: @fassl system() function is good for commands like "dir". when system("dir") be executed it gives you a list and then you're done. Think of a command like "ftp". when you execute ftp command it opens a session and wait for you to give it specific commands and when you're done you pass "quit" command and the ftp session ends. Doing such a thing with system() function is not possible. You can try it.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Christopher Oicles in the [referenced link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx), the logic using WinAPI is the same:

- you first create pipes for input and output - the WinAPI function is `CreatePipe`
- WinAPI allows to protect a handle for being inherited, because you do not have the `fork+exec` to close anything in the child - you must use `SetHandleInformation(handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);` before creating the child process
- you create the child process with `CreateProcess`, passing the handles to the pipes created above in the fields `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput` and `hStdError` of the `STARTUPINFO` struct - do not forget to declare that you want to use them with `dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;` in same struct.

This only makes sense with console application childs, because GUI subsystem application normally do not use standard streams, but it will work fine with the `ftp` command. Simply, as you process the streams yourself, the system do not create a console and the output from the child process is only available in the parent process.

---

In your code, there is at least one good reason for not writing what you expect. In `ReadFromPipe`, you get `bRead` bytes in your buffer, but you try to output the full buffer.

The output command should be:

```
bSuccess = WriteFile(hPARENT_STD_OUT, buffer, bRead, &bWritten, NULL);
```

But that is not all. A command should be terminated the same that it would be in a input file, that is with `\r\n`, so your command should be:

```
WriteToPipe(".databases\r\n");
```

And last but not least, you must close the unused parts of the pipes after starting child command, at least `hSTD_OUT_WRITE` to allow `ReadFile(hSTD_OUT_READ, ...)` to return 0 as soon as the child process exits. So your code should be:

```
CloseHandle(hSTD_OUT_WRITE);
CloseHandle(hSTD_IN_READ);

// Now execute your command then read the child process's output.
...
```

With those modifications, I could successfully communicate with the `ftp.exe` program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll appreciate if you check the updated question, please.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's so much better now. But how many command did you send to ftp.exe? it's OK with one single command. Obviously `if (!CloseHandle(hSTD_IN_WRITE))` in the `WriteToPipe(std::string)` function closes the handle and doesn't let me send commands multiple times. So I moved that just before `std::cout << "End of program.\n";`, still not working.

Comment: @Sam: I must admit that I made 2 working tests. One with your code but passing all ftp commands in one single string: `"open host.domain\r\nuser\r\npass\r\ndir\r\n"`, the other passing many separate commands with the `CloseHandle` commented out, and explicitely closing before calling `ReadPipe` to have the child nicely exit.

Comment: Yeah your pattern worked for me too. So it means we can't do this: `WriteToPipe("command1"); ReadFromPipe(); WriteToPipe("command2"); ReadFromPipe();` Because I need to execute my commands one after another then read each command's specific output then according to the ouput run the next command.

Comment: As you may understood from my previous comment, I need to analysis the output. So can I use a `std::stringstream or std::string` object instead of `hPARENT_STD_OUT` ???

Comment: Oh, there's no need for `std::stringstream or std::string`. I just need to remove `bSuccess = WriteFile(hPARENT_STD_OUT, ...)` then analysis the `buffer` that's all. But still need to run separate commands. `Run command1` `get the output` `run command2` `get the output`