# C++ - Use System Calls (fork, exec, wait etc) in Code Blocks

Tags: c++

im new to C++ and it was hard for me to find a good IDE. Now i have Code Blocks, but i cant use the Systemcalls like fork, wait etc.

I use Windows 7.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>;
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "I am " << (int) getpid() << endl;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    cout << "fork returned" << (int) pid << endl;
        return 0;

        if(pid<0) {
            cout << "Failed !" << endl;
            exit(3);
        }
        if(pid == 0) {
                cout << "i am the child" << (int) getpid() << endl;
                cout << "Child exiting" << endl;
                exit(0);

        }

        if(pid >= 0) {
            cout << "i am the parent" << (int) getpid() << endl;
            wait(NULL);
            cout << "Parent ending" << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I cant include sys/wait.h
Errors :

error : fork was not declared in this scope
error : wait was not declared in this scope

Thanks in advice !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use Windows 7.

Then indeed you are going to struggle using POSIX functions. Windows is not a POSIX OS.

You will need to use the Windows API's functions instead.

Take your list of project requirements, then research how to achieve each of them *in Windows*.

For example:

- [What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985281/560648)

Comment: There is also cygwin, but it can hurt ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork

Comment: I see edit 40 seconds ago and my comment is 58 seconds ago! So i think im clear of this Jinx ... Phew

Comment: @Ben: I said your name anyway. (Actually, they were only 13 seconds apart. Not sure where you're getting your timestamps from.)

Comment: Hello and thank you. would it be an solution if i install a virtual machine running ubuntu ?

Comment: @Raccoon20: Well, sure, Linux is largely POSIX-compatible so if you want to write C++ for Linux, switching to Linux will be a big step in the right direction. (It's not really relevant whether you use a virtual machine or a physical one.)

Comment: Ok. Would you recommend using gedit or code blocks for linux ?

Comment: @Raccoon20: IDE recommendations are off-topic.