# Program Get Stuck After Opening a Program Using System in c++

Tags: c++, shell, terminal, system

I want to open a program (that has terminal like CMD) with a C++ code, but when I try System() and that program opens, my C++ code get stuck until I close the program and the rest of the code will execute. I want to open a program that is a terminal and after opening, I want to send some commandS to program to execute it.
how can I:

1 - Continue to the rest of the C++ code after calling System() function

2 - Send a command to program using C++ code.

3 - receive command result

Here is the simple code that I use:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    system("path of the program");
    
    while(true)
    {
        // some commands that I want to send to terminal
        // receive result 
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `system` function in Windows C runtime library is "blocking". That means that the `system` command does not return until the program you are running with it exits.  If you must open a program from within your C++ code, you'll need to start a new process for it so that your code can continue running (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork) for some information on how to do that).

To send and receive information between your two programs, you'll need to implement some form of inter-process communication (ipc).  See [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) for how to get started on that.