# How to test the fork(); function on windows

Tags: c, gcc, fork, mingw-w64

I was trying the following code for an assignment in visual studio code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
int rc = fork();
if (rc < 0) {
// fork failed
fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
exit(1);
} else if (rc == 0) {
// child (new process)
printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
} else {
// parent goes down this path (main)
printf("hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n",
rc, (int) getpid());
}
return 0;
}
```

I initially had problems with the inbuilt compiler so I Switched to MinGW for windows gcc compiler which now gives me the error:

```
p1.c: In function 'main':
p1.c:9:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fork' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 int rc = fork();
          ^~~~
C:\Users\X1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGunGbh.o:p1.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `fork'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now as I understand the fork() function is missing from gcc or something. Is there any other compiler for C that I can try to test this function? or is there some workaround for gcc?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork/985525#985525).

Comment: Windows doesn't have `fork()`. Try installing Cygwin, it probably emulates it. Or install Linux.

Comment: A good first step would be installing WSL.

Comment: comment by @HolyBlackCat answers my query. I will test the same on my debian distribution.

Comment: On windows (with either VSC or mingw), this should give you an error about the non-existent include file unistd.h.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: My memory says there's a stripped-down unistd.h now with a few functions that really do exist in common.

Answer (score 2):

Go install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and build in that environment; then it will work.

There is no fork() on Windows and trying to make it is an exercise in straining your mind for no particularly good reason.