# Speed up extremely slow MinGW-w64 compilation/linking?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, linker, mingw-w64

How can I speed up MinGW-w64's *extremely* slow C++ compilation/linking?

Compiling a trivial "Hello World" program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

...takes *3 minutes*(!) on this otherwise-unloaded Windows 10 machine ([i7-6700](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88196/intel-core-i7-6700-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html), 32GB of RAM, decent SATA SSD):

```
> ptime.exe g++ main.cpp

ptime 1.0 for Win32, Freeware - http://www.pc-tools.net/
Copyright(C) 2002, Jem Berkes <jberkes@pc-tools.net>

===  g++ main.cpp ===

Execution time: 180.488 s
```

[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) shows the `g++` process tree bottoming out in `ld.exe` which doesn't use any appreciable CPU or I/O for the duration.

Running the `g++` process tree through [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) shows there are three unusually long syscalls in `ld.exe`: two `NtCreateFile()`s and a `NtOpenFile()`, each operating on `a.exe` and taking 60 seconds apiece.

The slowness only happens when using the default `a.exe` output; `g++ -o foo.exe main.cpp` takes 2 seconds, tops.

"Well don't use `a.exe` as an output name then!" isn't really a solution since this behavior causes CMake to take ages doing compiler feature detection.

GCC toolchain versions:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

>ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.30
```

Comment: I though maybe you have your folder over a network share, but like @genpfault said, it could be an AV issue, sounds more like it. I would say a) try starting windows on safe mode. b) Try compiling on a ramdrive folder (I do a shadow build on a ramdrive to speed up a large compile). c) What happends if you compile to foo.exe and then rename to a.exe or copy to a.exe? Does it take that much time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that I couldn't repro the problem in a clean Windows 10 VM and the dependence on the output filename led me down the path of anti-virus/anti-malware interference.

[`fltmc instances`](https://ss64.com/nt/fltmc.html) listed several possible filesystem filter drivers; guess-n-check narrowed it down to two of [Carbon Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_Black_(company))'s: `carbonblackk` & `ParityDriver`.

Using Regedit to disable them via setting `Start` to `0x4` ("Disabled", `0x2` == Automatic, `0x3` == Manual) in these two registry keys followed by a reboot fixed the slowness:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\carbonblackk
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ParityDriver

Answer (score 0):

To fix the slow linking issue you can use an alternative linker.

We sped up our GitHub action by adding this linker option `-fuse-ld=lld`

`-fuse-ld=lld` will use the llvm linker.

EX:

```
run: cmake -S. -B build -G "Ninja"
env:
    LDFLAGS: "-fuse-ld=lld" # MINGW linking is very slow. Use llvm linker instead.
```

Documentation for `LDFLAGS`:

> Will only be used by CMake on the first configuration to determine the default linker flags, after which the value for LDFLAGS is stored in the cache as CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT, CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT, and CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT. For any configuration run (including the first), the environment variable will be ignored if the equivalent CMAKE_<TYPE>_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT variable is defined.